# String->Structure CMap

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

My requirement is that given a string as key to the map, I should be able to retrieve a structure.

Can anyone please post sample code for this?

Ex:

```
struct
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
}struct_sample;
```

string1 -> strcut_sample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CMap<CString,LPCTSTR, struct_sample,struct_sample> myMap;

struct_sample aTest;
aTest.a = 1;
aTest.b = 2;
aTest.c = 3;
myMap.SetAt("test",aTest);
...

    struct_sample aLookupTest;
    BOOL bExists = myMap.Lookup("test",aLookupTest); //Retrieves the 
                             //struct_sample corresponding to "test".
```

Example from [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zshx6yzt(VS.80).aspx) for further details of CMap.

Comment: Some references talk about having to write your implementation of HashKey to use CString as a key.  So is this necessary or not?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to stick to MFC, go for the answer of aJ.

Else you're better of with a standard library map.  Be sure to check it's documentation - there's a lot to be learned.  I usually use http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility> // for make_pair

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::map< string, struct_sample > myMap;
    const struct_sample aTest = { 1,2,3 };
    myMap.insert(make_pair( "test", aTest ) );
    myMap[ "test2" ] = aTest; // does a default construction of the mapped struct, first => little slower than the map::insert

    const map<string, struct_sample >::const_iterator aLookupTest = myMap.find( "test" );
    const bool bExists = aLookupTest != myMap.end();

    aLookupTest->second.a = 10;
    myMap[ "test" ].b = 20;

}
```

Note: using a typedef for the templates may make the code more readable.

Comment: You didn't define "s". make_pair( "test", s ) will not compile. Please correct this so that it won't confuse people who are trying to learn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i was looking at MFC specific way to do it. Yes, i can go with your answer too. Once again thanks for the answer.